# mPDF Auto Generated PDF Mailer sends blank Email

Tags: php, email, pdf, phpmailer, mpdf

I am using mPDF class and am successfully able to generate an email with the following code. However, my email comes out blank. I am assuming but am not sure if this has something to do with my headers. It's hard for me to tell because I am getting my emails but am not able open the pdf it generates.

```
         include("./mpdf.php");

         $mpdf->debug = true;

         $html2 = '
              <div style="margin-left:3%;">Attach additional photos: 
              <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></div><hr />';

         echo $html2;



         if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
         $file_path = "webform.php";
         $file_path_type = "application/pdf";
              $mpdf=new mPDF('iso-8859-2');
              $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

         $file_path_name = "eval.pdf"; 
         $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n"; 
         $from = "info@myemail.com";
         $to = $_POST['email'];
         $ccto = $_POST['youremail'];
         $subject = "New Form Submitted"; 
         $message = "*** This is an automatically generated email, 
                   please do not reply *** Someone in your association 
                   has completed a survey.

         $headers = "From: ".$from;
         $headers.= "cc: " . $ccto . " <" . $ccto . ">" . "\n" ;
         $file = fopen($file_path,'rb');
         $data = fread($file,$file_path);
         fclose($file); 

         $rand = md5(time());
         $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$rand}x"; 

         $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

         $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message .= "\n\n"; 


         $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: {$file_path_type};\n" .
          " name=\"{$file_path_name}\"\n" .
          "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
          " filename=\"{$file_path_name}\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n" .
        $data .= "\n\n" .
          "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";  

        if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Document sent successfully!")';
        echo '</script>';
        echo "Sent!";

        } else {
        echo 'Failed';
        }
        }
        exit;
```

PHP mail and mpdf users any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're learning the hard way - Don't call `mail()` yourself because you will do it wrong; constructing and sending email messages is horribly complicated and full of pitfalls, as you're finding. Use a library, whether [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), SwiftMailer Zend_Mail etc, to do it and it will save you a great deal of hassle. You also need to check your two operations separately - first create a PDF, write it to a file and make sure it works correctly; Then write some code that sends a message and check that works; Then get it to send the PDF. Otherwise if you find it's not working, you won't be able to tell which part is broken.

Comment: Using your advice... I included phpmailer class which handled all the mime encoding a for me. My PDF generates nicely now thanks a million for the genius advice. @Synchro

Comment: "Horribly complicated and full of pitfalls".  I guess I need to add "extremely competent using mail()" to my resume.  (Oh, and omit "hardheaded and occasionally not convinced even by good arguments"...)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with MPDF and PHPMAILER.

I also have it so you can attach another file within my form that I made.  Hope this helps you along the way.

```
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {      

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','Letter','','','10','10','10','10','','');
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='ISO-8859-2';
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
$emailAttachment = $mpdf->Output('serviceagreement.pdf', 'S');
//$emailAttachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($emailAttachment));  

require("php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

$mail = new PHPMailer;           

$mail->AddAddress('send email');
$mail->SetFrom('support@myorganization.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email1']);
$mail->Subject = 'Evaluation';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail->MsgHTML("*** Form attached! Please see the attached form (.pdf).");
$mail->AddStringAttachment($emailAttachment, $filename = 'serviceagreement.pdf',
      $encoding = 'base64',
      $type = 'application/pdf');      // attachment
if (isset($_FILES['attached']) &&
    $_FILES['attached']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attached']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['attached']['name']);
}
$mail->Send();
echo "<div style='margin-left:4%;'>Message Sent OK</div>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}}

?>'
```