# Sending PDF email with MPDF

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mpdf

I have set up the system where while clicking on button, the contract is send with pdf attached.I have used mpdf to send the email to the required email address.
The following code is working fine on my local host and does the job correctly but when i put it on the server,it is not showing any error but also not sending any email as in I don't receive anything. 
Can you help me figure out what maybe am i doing wrong?

```
// Setup PDF
    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'Letter', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
    ob_start();
    $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf top margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
    $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf bottom margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // Writing style to pdf
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // Writing html to pdf
    // FOR EMAIL
    $content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); // Saving pdf to attach to email 
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $emailto = 'abc@abc.com';
    //The function to send email when the contract is requested
    $recepients = array(
      $email,
      'abc@abc.com'
      );
    $mailto = implode(',', $recepients);
    $from_name = 'Random Project';
    $from_mail = 'abc@abc.com';
    $replyto = 'abc@abc.com';
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time())); 
    $subject = 'Wedding Contract Form';
    $message =  '
      </<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      </style> 
      <body>
      <img src="http://tanglewoodestate.com.au/assets/contract-header.png" width="400px">
      <div width ="300px" style="background-color:#f5e9dd;padding:10px">
      <p>Hi <strong>'.$cname.'</strong>,<p>
      <p>Please Find the <strong>attached contract</strong> from the Tanglewood Estate.</p>
      <p>For any questions or queries,Please contact Us at:<br>
      ABC<br>
      abc@abc.com<br>
      </div>
      <img src="http://tanglewoodestate.com.au/assets/contract-footer.png" width="400px">
      </body>
      </html>';
    $filename = 'Wedding_contract.pdf';
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    $is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
    //$mpdf->Output(); // For sending Output to browser

    //$mpdf->Output('Wedding_contract.pdf','D'); // For Download
    ob_end_flush();
    }
```

Comment: not sending and not receiving are not the same thing

Comment: your much better off using one of the standard mailing libraries such as phpmailer than mail()

Comment: rtfms - Only if you can understand that for testing purposes i am sending that to myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is taken from the thread:[mPDF Auto Generated PDF Mailer sends blank Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377396/mpdf-auto-generated-pdf-mailer-sends-blank-email) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3818025/drehx

So , I just used PHP Mailer to send the email. Just posting this to help anybody who would want to use it as example:

```
try {

$mail = new PHPMailer; 
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->AddAddress('abc@abc.com');
$mail->AddAddress('abc@abc.com');
$mail->SetFrom('abc@abc.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('abc@abc.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Tanglewood Contract';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = '</<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  </style> 
  <body>
  <img src="http://tanglewoodestate.com.au/assets/contract-header.png" width="400px">
  <div width ="300px" style="background-color:#f5e9dd;padding:10px">
  <p>Hi <strong>'.$cname.'</strong>,<p>
  <p>Please Find the <strong>attached contract</strong> from the Tanglewood Estate.</p>
  <p>For any questions or queries,Please contact Us at:<br>
  Tanglewood Estate<br>
  abc@abc.com<br>
  </div>
  <img src="http://tanglewoodestate.com.au/assets/contract-footer.png" width="400px">
  </body>
  </html>';

//$mail->MsgHTML("*** Form attached! Please see the attached form (.pdf).");
$mail->AddStringAttachment($content, $filename = 'TanglewoodContract.pdf',
      $encoding = 'base64',
      $type = 'application/pdf');      // attachment
if (isset($_FILES['attached']) &&
    $_FILES['attached']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attached']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['attached']['name']);
}
$mail->Send();
echo "<div style='margin-left:4%;'>Message Sent OK</div>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```